# System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form when invoking NServiceBus via Hangfire task

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, nservicebus, hangfire

I get the below error when I try to invoke NServiceBus/Rabbit MQ via a Hangfire Task
I have tried updating the .NET Framework version from 4.5.2 to 4.6.1

Not sure what is it that I'm doing wrong here?
I keep getting this error
However, when I run this locally (via a Test Project), then the message is successfully placed on the Service Bus (am able to see it on the Service Endpoint)

```
    System.AggregateException
One or more errors occurred.

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetFullPathWithAssert(String fileName)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
   at NServiceBus.Transport.RabbitMQ.ConnectionConfiguration.Create(String connectionString, String endpointName) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a9e6741f41af7061\src\NServiceBus.RabbitMQ\Configuration\ConnectionConfiguration.cs:line 141
   at NServiceBus.Transport.RabbitMQ.RabbitMQTransportInfrastructure..ctor(SettingsHolder settings, String connectionString) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a9e6741f41af7061\src\NServiceBus.RabbitMQ\RabbitMQTransportInfrastructure.cs:line 29
   at NServiceBus.RabbitMQTransport.Initialize(SettingsHolder settings, String connectionString) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a9e6741f41af7061\src\NServiceBus.RabbitMQ\RabbitMQTransport.cs:line 18
   at NServiceBus.InitializableEndpoint.<Initialize>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\b549d46003942065\src\NServiceBus.Core\InitializableEndpoint.cs:line 49
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.Endpoint.<Start>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\b549d46003942065\src\NServiceBus.Core\Endpoint.cs:line 27
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ERM.Messaging.ServiceBus.Client.ServiceBusClient.<StartAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MeterServiceRequest.SyncMeterServiceRequest.<RunAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MeterServiceRequest.SyncMeterServiceRequest.<RunAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at ERM.TaskRunner.Server.Impl.TaskWrapper.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Code\EMSCore\Apps\TaskRunner\TaskRunner.Server\Impl\TaskWrapper.cs:line 29
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetFullPathWithAssert(String fileName)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
   at NServiceBus.Transport.RabbitMQ.ConnectionConfiguration.Create(String connectionString, String endpointName) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a9e6741f41af7061\src\NServiceBus.RabbitMQ\Configuration\ConnectionConfiguration.cs:line 141
   at NServiceBus.Transport.RabbitMQ.RabbitMQTransportInfrastructure..ctor(SettingsHolder settings, String connectionString) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a9e6741f41af7061\src\NServiceBus.RabbitMQ\RabbitMQTransportInfrastructure.cs:line 29
   at NServiceBus.RabbitMQTransport.Initialize(SettingsHolder settings, String connectionString) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a9e6741f41af7061\src\NServiceBus.RabbitMQ\RabbitMQTransport.cs:line 18
   at NServiceBus.InitializableEndpoint.<Initialize>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\b549d46003942065\src\NServiceBus.Core\InitializableEndpoint.cs:line 49
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.Endpoint.<Start>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\b549d46003942065\src\NServiceBus.Core\Endpoint.cs:line 27
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ERM.Messaging.ServiceBus.Client.ServiceBusClient.<StartAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Comment: Looks like the connection string is the issue?

Comment: Can you find out what the value of `typeof(NServiceBus.Endpoint).Assembly.Location` and `typeof(NServiceBus.RabbitMQTransport).Assembly.Location` are when run from inside your Hangfire task?

Comment: @SeanFarmar no have checked the Connection string, also, when I try to put a message to the NServiceBus via the Test Project it works (with the same connection string)

Comment: did you try @Brandon Ording's suggestion?

Comment: @SeanFarmar yes, Barndon's suggestion made us look in the direction of the below posted answer

Answer (score 1):

We resolved the issue by placing the NService Bus files (including DLLs) on the same server where the Hangfire Tasks were located and add the references to NService Bus on the Hangfire task solution